# How to add note annotation pop up and save some text PDFKit iOS11

Tags: ios, swift

I have tried this code not working. Only line and other annotation are working .

```
if (pdfview.currentSelection != nil)
{

    let rect = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: (pdfview.currentSelection?.bounds(for: pdfview.currentPage!).minY)!, width: 45, height: 45)

    let ann = PDFAnnotation(bounds: rect, forType: PDFAnnotationSubtype.text, withProperties: nil)
    ann.iconType = .comment
    pdfview.currentPage?.addAnnotation(ann)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    let rect = CGRect.init(x: 20, y: 20, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 45)
    let ann = PDFAnnotation(bounds: rect, forType: PDFAnnotationSubtype.widget, withProperties: nil)
    ann.widgetFieldType = .text
    ann.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    pdfView.currentPage?.addAnnotation(ann)
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "\(pdfname)", withExtension: "pdf")
    {
        pdfView.document?.write(to: url)
    }
```

Comment: it works increased the size of annotation thank you @Balaji

Comment: Refer apple documentation for more details